# Trouble applying newly defined CSS rules

Tags: html, css, paragraph

I am having trouble understanding how CSS rules are applied.

For a paragraph in a div, I want to apply this newly defined rule:

```
.imgDescription {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    color: #000; 
}
```

but the paragraph is still styled by the preceding rule:

```
.dark-wrapper .inner p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size:14px;
    color:#CCC;
}
```

I don't know how to fix this.

Comment: Try : `.dark-wrapper .inner p.imgDescription `

Answer (score 0):

You could add `!important` to your styles.

```
.imgDescription {
    position: absolute !important;
    right: 10px !important;
    color: #000 !important;
}
```

Or define the `.imgDescription` under the `.dark-wrapper .inner p`-part. As far as I know, CSS-definitions are weighted according to their order in the definition. Correct me, if I'm wrong here...

Comment: In the OP, the preceding rule happens to be more specific, which is why the newly written rule is not taken effect.  `!important` is a fix but will probably make the stylesheet harder to maintain.  The smarter money is on using a more specific selector.

Answer (score 0):

You need to understand how CSS rules work, namely, the cascade and specificity.

You can read: http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html

In your case, you need to make your new rule more specific so that it overrides the previously defined rule.

In your example, you would need:

```
.dark-wrapper .inner p {
    font-family: 'Open Sans';
    font-size:14px;
    color:#CCC;
}

.dark-wrapper .inner p.imgDescription {
    position: absolute;
    right: 10px;
    color: #000; 
}
```

`.dark-wrapper .inner p` has a specificity of 0,0,2,1

`.dark-wrapper .inner p.imgDescription` has a specificity of 0,0,3,1 which is higher and will take precedence.